# jQuery will not work when added into WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#found-result').hide();
$('#found-no-result').hide();
$('.colors-li').hide();
$('#search-mod').click(function(){
  var searchCriteria = $('#search-criteria').val().toUpperCase();
  var isFound = false; // Display "Success or Failure"
  $('.colors-list').each(function(){
     var tagA = $(this).find('.colors-li-a')[0];
     var Value = $(tagA).text().toUpperCase();
     var isMached = Value == searchCriteria || searchCriteria == "";
     $(this).toggle(isMached);
     
     
     if(isMached) isFound = true; // Display "Success or Failure"
  }); 

   $("#result-success").html(isFound ? $("#found-result").show() : $("#found-no-result").show()); 
  
});
```

It goes on a WordPress page along with a search box made with HTML, it allows a user to search for a colour and responds with if the colour is available.

I have tried to add the script to the site by adding this into my functions.php

```
function jquery_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'color-check', '/js/colorcheck.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'color-check' );
    
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_load_scripts');
```

If I go onto the page where it is used and use the search console, I can see the script is loaded in at the top, but the script doesn't work at all. I have been developing this in a JSFiddle and it is working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the jquery code inside a `$(document).ready` function. It's likely the code is being run before the DOM is ready

Comment: Wordpress may run `jQuery` in `noConflict` mode.  I would suggest going to your page, opening the developer tools, going to the console, and typing `$.fn.jquery`.  If you get a version number, jQuery is registered as `$`.  If you don't, try `jQuery.fn.jquery`.  If you get version number with that, then you have jQuery on the page and it definitely is running in noConflict mode.

Comment: There is a good tutorial here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

Comment: @Taplar is most likely right. Replace instances of `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: @Taplar I entered jQuery.fn.jquery & received "3.5.1", so I went through my code and replaced $ for jQuery and it didn't work. I then also tried evolutionxbox's suggestion both with and without $ and still, it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Put your logic in a document ready block that uses `jQuery` and passes in jQuery as `$`.  Example: `jQuery(function($){ ...your logic here that can use $ as you expect it to work... });`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your $( statements with the full jQuery(

e.g

```
$('#found-result').hide();
$('#found-no-result').hide();
$('.colors-li').hide();
$('#search-mod').click(function(){
```

becomes:

```
jQuery('#found-result').hide();
jQuery('#found-no-result').hide();
jQuery('.colors-li').hide();
jQuery('#search-mod').click(function(){
```

etc